# Laravel payment callback not working on local host

Tags: php, laravel, gateway

I am very new to the concept of payment gateways especially in Laravel. I am developing a store in offline mode (localhost:8000). Although I have declared the link of callback from bank, the callback is made to `localhost/` and not `localhost:8000` which is needed.
Below is the code from my routes file: `web.php`

```
Route::get('/buy',function(){
    try {

        $gateway = \Gateway::zarinpal();
        $gateway->setCallback(url('http://localhost:8000/PaymentSuccessfulController'));
        $gateway->price(1000)->ready(); //Rials
        $refId =  $gateway->refId();
        $transID = $gateway->transactionId();

        // Your code here

        return $gateway->redirect();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
});

Route::any('PaymentSuccessfulController',function(){
    try {

        $gateway = \Gateway::verify();
        $trackingCode = $gateway->trackingCode();
        $refId = $gateway->refId();
        $cardNumber = $gateway->cardNumber();

        // Your code here
        echo 'Card Number: ' . $cardNumber . '<br />';
        echo 'Tracking Code: ' . $trackingCode . '<br />';

        }
         catch (RetryException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
         catch (PortNotFoundException $e) 
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
         catch (InvalidRequestException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
         catch (NotFoundTransactionException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
         catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
});
```

The transactions get done successfully, but when they are finished and the browser redirects to where it should, I receive the `404 Not Found` and the address bar value would be:

> http://localhost/PaymentSuccessfulController?transaction_id=xxxxxxxxx

Is it possible to do banking transactions successfully from localhost? If so, how would it be possible for me to fix the problem?

Comment: I am using `Gateway` module which is a fork of `PoolPort`. I live in Iran and have no access to `Paypal`.

Comment: Maybe better if you use another method to developing your project on localhost, for example [homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead)

Comment: Thank you both gentlemen. I created a virtualhost and my laravel installation is running fine now. That was a very great help. Thank you very much again.